# How do I get the background image to cover the whole div?

Tags: html, css

hay guy I'm a new developer to css and html and right now I can't tell if it my computer or my code that giving me issues. I'm trying to get it so the pic of Tayler Swift and her friends are taking up the entirety of back ground of just the "header_slogan_title" div. The div needs a height of 700px and fill the width of the page. The code I have is below.

```
<header>
    <div class="header_title">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title">Fashist Fashion</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="title_opt">
      <nav>
         <a href="#header_slogan_title">Mission</a>
         <a>Featured Clothing Lines</a>
         <a>Locations</a>
       </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="header_slogan_title">
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <h4>To bring creative, hunger driven, freely forced apon, high fashion to all comrads</h4>
    </div>
------------------------------------------------------
html{
    background-color: red;
}


.header_title{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.title_opt a {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.header_slogan_title{
    text-align: center;
    height: 700px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(../Anarchy_Web/pics/banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Try checking the file path here:

```
background-image: url(../Anarchy_Web/pics/banner.jpg);
```

you can check by replacing with an external link:

```
background-image: url(https://image.insider.com/5dcebbb779d7570274675e72?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp);
```

https://codepen.io/opmasan/pen/MWaZxWY